# Looping through CQWP li's

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-query-web-part

I have a CQWP that executes the following JS:

```
var projectstartdt = $(".hiddenProjectStartDate").html().split(/\-|\s/);
var ProjectStart = new Date(projectstartdt.slice(0,3).join('/')+' '+projectstartdt[3]);

var projectenddt = $(".hiddenProjectEndDate").html().split(/\-|\s/);
var ProjectEnd = new Date(projectenddt.slice(0,3).join('/')+' '+projectenddt[3]);

var milestone1date = ((Milestone1Date-ProjectStart)/(ProjectEnd-ProjectStart)*100);
$(".wj-cqwp-ProjectMilestone1").css( "left", milestone1date + "%");

var milestone2date = ((Milestone2Date-ProjectStart)/(ProjectEnd-ProjectStart)*100);
$(".wj-cqwp-ProjectMilestone2").css("left", milestone2date + "%");
```

This code isn't the problem. It's working as expected. Problem is, I need this to fire for every li within a CQWP. Specifically every

```
.wj-cqwp-ProjectDashboard ul li
```

I've tried using a jQuery each function, but to no avail!

```
$( ".wj-cqwp-ProjectDashboard ul li" ).each(function() {
// big chunk of code above entered here
});
```

Help! Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to wrap or delay that function until SharePoint controls finish loading that with `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`:

So:

```
function fireOnListItems(){

$( ".wj-cqwp-ProjectDashboard ul li" ).each(function() {
// big chunk of code above entered here
});

}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fireOnListItems");
```